# "When he went out he left the radio on so that his parents shall think that he was still in the house"

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs

> When he went out he left the radio on so that his parents **shall
>   think** that he was still in the house.

This is a past sentence. Why is *shall think* used? Can I use *should think*?

Comment: use *would think*

Comment: "shall think" is uncommon in the United States. I mostly hear it from people where English is not their primary language. `Would think` sounds perfect.

Comment: Yes - it would be helpful to know the source of your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Should think* is technically correct, since this was the object of his action, not the consequence. *Would think* is so common that  only pedants would object, should you use it.

*Shall think* cannot be correct in this situation; without more context we can't say why the author thought it might be.

Edit to support the first sentence: "Roughly, *shall* and *should* are used when the word on which the *that*-clause depends expresses an influence that affects the result, as a demand does, but a hope or fear does not. In 'England expects that every man will do his duty', the substitution of *shall* for *will* would convert an expression of confidence into an exhortation." Fowler (ed. Burchfield), *sv* 'shall and will'.  The article ends by saying "But the American practice of omitting the auxiliary in such sentences is becoming increasingly common in Britain: *I am anxious that... the right site be selected*"; I don't know whether this really is American practice, but it is rare (though not unknown) in the British circles I move in.

Comment: _Would_ is usually preferred over _should_ in this context in American English. We've lost the subtlety of the _would/should_ distinction.

Comment: I would also have used *would* in BrE. *shall* is wrong, and (at best) *should* sounds 'affected'.

Comment: I agree with Trevor. ‘Should’ sounds more than just affected to me here—it sounds quite _strange_ and even downright wrong. Even in other Germanic languages where the ‘should/would’ distinction is much more clearly marked (though of course in slightly different ways also), ‘would’ would be the correct verb to apply here, rather than ‘should’. I’m afraid I don’t quite follow the object vs. consequence distinction here: surely it would simply have been ‘thought’ if it were a consequence?

Answer (score -1):

Use "should", and a comma is missing after *on*. Read the sentence aloud; don't you mark a pause?

Comment: Actually no I don't, any more than in 'I cashed a cheque so that I could buy a drink.'